# Windows Server 2003 Terminal Services error

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, terminal-services

I have a Win2K3 machine which I want to access via remote desktop. When I try remote desktop on another machine the session just ends as soon as it attempts connection. I never see the log-on sceeen or anything. It just returns to the remote desktop connection dialog.

I have checked the service on the target machine and it's up and running, so how can I determine the error? Is there any way to re-install terminal services and see if it just fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check your even log on both your client and server machines. 
That should give you a bit more of an idea. Without seeing what's in there I can't really say any more.

Also - It could be worth upgrading your client to the latest version. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084

Answer (score 0):

It may be a licensing issue, try logging on using the /admin command line switch for mstsc.exe, which will connect you to an administrative remote desktop session, instead of using up a TS CAL. Then you can diagnose further.